# Function that will check if there is already a folder by that name

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel-formula, save, filenames

I'm trying to create a save function that will check if there is already a folder by the name specified in Range `G3` and if there is, it will just save the file. If there isn't it will create a new folder by that name and save the file.

```vb
Sub ExportAsCSV()
 
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
    Dim sFilename As String
    Const csPath As String = "C:\Users\gald\Desktop\Vintage - Gal\Hourly"
    
    sFilename = Range("G2")
    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
 
    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
    
    Rows("1:6").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    With Range("J2:W200")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    MyFileName = csPath & "\" & Left(sFilename, Len(sFilename)) & ".csv"
     
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help = )

Answer (score 0):

Use API MakeSureDirectoryPathExists
Example Module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal lpPath As String) As Long
Sub TestIt()
Dim testPath As String
' E:\ if you dont have a Drive E use one You Got
testPath = "E:\MyNewFolder\Somewhere\"
If CreateFolderIfNotExists(testPath) Then
MsgBox ("Yes there is one at least now")
Else
MsgBox ("No there is a Problem")
End If
End Sub
' Creates the folder if not exists and returns true or returns true if folder already exists
Public Function CreateFolderIfNotExists(FolderPath As String) As Boolean
CreateFolderIfNotExists = MakeSureDirectoryPathExists(FolderPath) = 1
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean? I didn't have the chance to work with API's

Comment: I changed my answer to a full example, I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I created a helpful function for ensuring the folder exists.

First, set the library reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

This function works by passing in the `folderPath` (make sure you have it formatted with your systems `PathSeparator`) and it will split that path into an array.

Then the code iterates each path, building on top of each one create each sub folder as needed.

Lastly, if all goes well the return value will be `True`

```vb
' Creates a full path, iterating at each
' step. FSO.CreateFolder only does a single level.
' @LibraryReference {Microsoft Scripting Runtime}
Public Function EnusureFolderExists(ByVal folderPath As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo catch
    ' Separate the paths
    Dim paths() As String
    paths = Split(folderPath, Application.PathSeparator)
    
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim pathIndex As Integer
        For pathIndex = LBound(paths, 1) To UBound(paths, 1)
            ' Each iteration will build the next
            ' level of the full path
            Dim currentPath As String
            currentPath = currentPath & paths(pathIndex) & Application.PathSeparator
            
            ' If current iteration doesn't exist then
            ' create it
            If Not .FolderExists(currentPath) Then
                .createFolder currentPath
            End If
        Next
        
        ' No failures, returns if it exists
        EnusureFolderExists = .FolderExists(folderPath)
    End With
    
Exit Function
catch:
    ' On any error it will return false
End Function
```

To use it in your code:

```vb
Sub ExportAsCSV()
    Const csPath As String = "C:\Users\gald\Desktop\Vintage - Gal\Hourly"
    
    If EnusureFolderExists(csPath) = False Then
        ' An issue occurred in created the folder, 
        ' you need to handle that what happens in that senerio.
        MsgBox "Unable to create folder: " & csPath, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' ... Rest of your code
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't insert it into my code.
Can you help me understand how to combine it with what I've already done?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of using the function in your code. Again, make sure you have the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for it to work.